# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_crypt'

Tags: python, windows, crypt

I'm trying to use Flask and started with first example, while running the below code

```
from crypt import methods
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return "Hello world"


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(port=3000, debug=True)
```

I got the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_crypt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3sjA.png)

Comment: I've already tried to install the crypt module but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

`crypt` is a [Unix Specific Service](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unix.html), and not supported on Windows OS.

Right at the top of the [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/crypt.html) for `crypt`:

> 34.5. crypt — Function to check Unix passwords
>
> **Platforms: Unix**

Alternative is to use passlib:

```
from passlib.hash import md5_crypt as md5
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt as sha256
from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt as sha512

md5_passwd = md5.encrypt(passwd, rounds=5000, implicit_rounds=True)
sha256_passwd = sha256.encrypt(passwd, rounds=5000, implicit_rounds=True)
sha512_passwd = sha512.encrypt(passwd, rounds=5000, implicit_rounds=True)
```

Comment: You mean I have to add these lines into the file crypt.py

Comment: The first lines of the file crypt.py: import sys as _sys

try:
    import _crypt
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    if _sys.platform == 'win32':
        raise ImportError("The crypt module is not supported on Windows")
    else:
        raise ImportError("The required _crypt module was not built as part of CPython")

Comment: I means it's a Unix/Linux OS package and not supported in windows OS. For that I have added an alternative.

Comment: if you are using VS Code remove this from the top of the file: `from crypt import methods`  sometimes its automatically added.